# Can Blazor Server be configured not to use inline styles

Tags: blazor-server-side, content-security-policy

The Blazor CSP directive seems to imply no inline styles are used, since it uses style-src 'self'.
However when applying the style-src 'self' policy, several csp errors are thrown.

Is there a configuration I am missing to force Blazor not to use inline styles? Or do I need to add a hash myself?

**Content Security Policy for Blazor Server:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="base-uri 'self';
      default-src 'self';
      img-src data: https:;
      object-src 'none';
      script-src 'self';
      style-src 'self';
      upgrade-insecure-requests;">
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/content-security-policy?view=aspnetcore-7.0

**One example of a CSP error in the browser:**

```
blazor.server.js:1 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-mBOLIpCiEczo5ZIWAXklxWfEkgQytZbq3p0NQpliwjI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
 
applyAttribute @ blazor.server.js:1
insertElement @ blazor.server.js:1
insertFrame @ blazor.server.js:1
applyEdits @ blazor.server.js:1
updateComponent @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
processBatch @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
_invokeClientMethod @ blazor.server.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.server.js:1
Ft.connection.onreceive @ blazor.server.js:1
i.onmessage @ blazor.server.js:1
```

Comment: I don't think Blazor ever uses inline styles - are you sure it's not your own components or 3rd party components?

Comment: Maybe I was to quick assuming it was Blazor itself because the error occurs in blazor.server.js, but I guess it could come from anywhere. I don't use inline styles myself, but it might be the Telerik Components we use. I will have to investigate.

Comment: Yes, the error will be in the blazor javascript because that is what updates the DOM. I don't think there is any way to globally prevent  use of inline styles in Blazor, but you may be able to detect them by analysing the `RenderTreeFrames` generated by the components, looking for style attributes, but it's probably easier to disable your CSP, render the site and search for inline styles in the browser